# Using If Then Else statement against selected records in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select, if-else

I am working on a Python script that will count how many selected features there are and if there are it will make a feature layer from them.  If the script runs and finds there are 0 selected records it should print 'NO SELECTED RECORDS'.  However when I run my script it is ignoring my If Then statement and creating a duplicate layer of "Locates", but still telling me I have no records selected.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy

totalCount = arcpy.GetCount_management("Locates")
print 'Total Record Count = ' + `totalCount`
try:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Locates","INTERSECT","Boxes",0,"NEW_SELECTION","INVERT")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Locates","INTERSECT","Lines",0,"REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION")
    ##GET COUNT OF SELECTED RECORDS
    selectedCount = len(arcpy.Describe("Locates").FIDSet.split('; '))-1
    print 'Selected Records Count' + `selectedCount`
    if selectedCount != totalCount:
        ##IF SELECTED ROWS NOT EQUAL TO 0 THEN MAKE FEATURE LAYER ELSE PRINT 'NO LOCATES TO CLOSE'
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Locates","NeedToCLOSE")
        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("NeedToCLOSE"):
            print 'Close Work Order #' + `row.WorkOrderID`
    else:
        print 'No Locates to close'
except:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

What do I need to change in my code for this to work?

Comment: See help on getCount. You need int(result[0]) to treat it as integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FelixIP comments, you need to convert your `getCount()` result to an integer

```
result = arcpy.GetCount_management("Locates")
totalCount = int(result[0])
```

See the code sample in [Get Count - Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm)

Comment: Do you know how I would alter my code to convert it into a script tool?